# Simple algorithm to create round robin league in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I need a simple algorithm for make the league games which for 4 and 6 teams works fine.
For example we have 4 teams:

`[a, b, c, d]`

We will have (4-1) weeks and I want to know every week games:

**Week 1:**

```
a - b
c - d
```

**Week 2:**

```
a - c
b - d
```

**Week 3**:

```
a - d
c - b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic algorithm, that works for all numbers of teams. 
It is a standard algorithm that follows the explanations described in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)

```
$teams = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') ;
create_round_robin_tournament($teams);

function create_round_robin_tournament($teams)
{
    if(count($teams) < 2) throw new Exception("At least 2 teams needed to build tournament");

    if( count($teams) % 2 == 1 )
        $teams[] = "dummy" ; // if number of teams is even, add a dummy team that means 'this team don't play this round'

    for($round = 0 ; $round < count($teams)-1 ; ++$round)
    {
        echo "=== Round " . ($round+1) . " ===" . PHP_EOL ;
        displayRoundPairs($teams);
        echo PHP_EOL ;
        $teams = rotateCompetitors($teams);
    }
}

function displayRoundPairs($teams)
{
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($teams)/2 ; ++$i)
    {
        $opponent = count($teams) - 1 - $i ;

        if($teams[$i] == 'dummy')
            echo "Team " . $teams[$opponent] . " don't play this round" . PHP_EOL ;
        elseif($teams[$opponent] == 'dummy')
            echo "Team " . $teams[$i] . " don't play this round" . PHP_EOL ;
        else 
            echo $teams[$i] . ' - ' . $teams[$opponent] . PHP_EOL ;
    }
}

// rotate all competitors but the first one
function rotateCompetitors($teams)
{
    $result = $teams ;

    $tmp = $result[ count($result) - 1 ] ;
    for($i = count($result)-1 ; $i > 1 ; --$i)
    {
        $result[$i] = $result[$i-1] ;
    }
    $result[1] = $tmp ;

    return $result ;

}
```

Comment: Great response, Thank you Joffrey.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for answering this, it came in super handy. :-)